# Can you run Wordpress on a MarketLive/Java EE server?

Tags: php, server

I am using MarketLive. I want to install Wordpress into a subfolder, but the person I'm speaking with says they can't do it because my site is built in Java. I want to install wordpress on my domain because I want to set up a blog, and it's a quick and way to do so.

I don't understand this. All that Wordpress needs to run is PHP. PHP can be installed in a Windows or Linux environment. So, what is stopping this from happening?

I'm not sure if what the company is telling me is correct or if they are just trying to get more money from me (installing Wordpress and allowing me to set up my own blog vs them creating a blog for me).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is programming language and software that interprets and runs code written in that programming language. But PHP is not web server - software that responds to requests, puts together and sends pages to visitors.

If you are using web server that cannot use PHP then your only option is to add another web server that is capable of that. Which of course comes with setup and integration issues.

The low hanging fruit solution in your case would probably be setting up separate site under *blog.yourdomain.com* or something, with setup appropriate for WordPress and handle it separately from main site.

Answer (score 0):

As Wordpress is PHP you'll need something to run it in. Apache Webserver with the PHP module installed can do this.

Your Java EE server (Tomcat, Jboss, Glassfish or whatever it is) cannot typically be used to run PHP.

If you want an all Java blog solution then you could look at Apache Roller. Its nowhere near as nice as Wordpress but can be installed in a Java EE server. Its not trivial though and requires a certain level of setting up.